# form in subpage doesn't work

Tags: php, html

I have my page as follows:

```
<form id="filterQuery" action="#" method="post">
   ...
   <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
  // use $_POST to determine query restrictions and conditions
?>
```

Now my problem is with the action of the form, because if I make it "#" self, nothing happens when clicking submit.

I'm using a template which shows subpages as `include` in `<div>`s. In other words, my page is not a standard HTML page which contain `<head>` and `<body>` etc, but is in the following format: `basic.php#!/my_sub_page`.

Trying to make action `"basic.php#!/my_sub_page"` results in an empty `_POST`

Comment: don`t write # for self just leave empty for self url action=""

Comment: @AnandPatel This is not working too (empty _POST)

Comment: try this action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>"

Comment: Thanks, but this cause the subpage to be viewed alone, without its base page. (i.e. making the href="my_sub_page.php" instead of ""basic.php#!/my_sub_page")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your example and everything works fine with `/index.php#!/smth` in action and post variables.

```
<form action="#!/something" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="var1" value="123">
    <input type="submit"></form>
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This is how I check it.

Are you sure you didn't forget name attributes in inputs?

Do you see their values in url after `?` if you change method to get?

Comment: It is not working with post. I really see the parameters on the url when using `get`, but `var_dump($_GET)` shows it empty!!

Comment: @user3441905, Paste your get url please

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/cms/admin/showroom.php?startDate=2014-11-07&endDate=2014-12-07&cache=on&rental=on&view=View++%DA%D1%D6#!/showroom_report_7arMab`

Comment: Here, the basic is `showroom.php`, the sub is `showroom_report_7arMab`. `_GET` is empty

Comment: @user3441905, yes, you can't, fotunately. SO is not a place where you have to downvote every answer, that didn't help you. You'll have enough score to do it, when you understand it. In your case, empty request array with parameters in url means, that it's overwritten before.